# Login Remotely and Display Content using cURL in PHP

Tags: php, curl, authentication, libcurl

I am using cURL in PHP to login to a remote server of mine. I have successfully logged in the remote URL but I cannot seem to display the content of that page. Here is my code so far:

```
<?php

$username = 'Blah';
$password = 'BlahBlah';

$ch = curl_init();
$postdata="email=$username&password=$password";
curl_setopt ($ch, CURLOPT_URL,"http://www.example.com/login.php");
curl_setopt ($ch, CURLOPT_SSL_VERIFYPEER, FALSE);
curl_setopt ($ch, CURLOPT_USERAGENT, "Mozilla/5.0 (Windows; U; Windows NT 5.1; en-US; rv:1.8.1.6) Gecko/20070725 Firefox/2.0.0.6");
curl_setopt ($ch, CURLOPT_HEADER, true);
curl_setopt ($ch, CURLOPT_FOLLOWLOCATION, true);
curl_setopt ($ch, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, 1);
curl_setopt ($ch, CURLOPT_COOKIEJAR, 'cookie.txt');
curl_setopt ($ch, CURLOPT_COOKIEFILE, 'cookie.txt');
curl_setopt ($ch, CURLOPT_REFERER, "http://www.example.com/login.php");
curl_setopt ($ch, CURLOPT_POSTFIELDS, $postdata);
curl_setopt ($ch, CURLOPT_POST, 1);
$result = curl_exec($ch);

curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_URL, "http://www.example.com/User/Home.php") ;
$result2 = curl_exec($ch) ;

echo $result2 ;

curl_close($ch);

?>
```

When I try echoing `$result2`, nothing is there. Nothing is printed to the screen. What do I need to do in order to have the content printed to the screen?

Here is the HTTP Header output:

```
HTTP/1.1 302 Moved Temporarily Date: Sun, 26 May 2013 23:46:40 GMT Server: Apache/2.2.23 (Unix) mod_ssl/2.2.23 OpenSSL/0.9.8e-fips-rhel5 mod_bwlimited/1.4 Expires: Thu, 19 Nov 1981 08:52:00 GMT Cache-Control: no-store, no-cache, must-revalidate, post-check=0, pre-check=0 Pragma: no-cache Set-Cookie: current_page=Home.php; expires=Wed, 24-May-2023 23:46:40 GMT Location: http://www.example.com/?redirected=3 Vary: Accept-Encoding,User-Agent Content-Length: 0 Content-Type: text/html HTTP/1.1 200 OK Date: Sun, 26 May 2013 23:46:40 GMT Server: Apache/2.2.23 (Unix) mod_ssl/2.2.23 OpenSSL/0.9.8e-fips-rhel5 mod_bwlimited/1.4 Expires: Thu, 19 Nov 1981 08:52:00 GMT Cache-Control: no-store, no-cache, must-revalidate, post-check=0, pre-check=0 Pragma: no-cache Vary: Accept-Encoding,User-Agent Transfer-Encoding: chunked Content-Type: text/html
```

Answer (score 0):

It probably isn't following redirects. use:

```
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_FOLLOWLOCATION, true);
```

Comment: I just realized that my remote site is using $_SESSIONS and not $_COOKIES. What would I need to do for that?

Comment: it's still using cookies. You can't have sessions without cookies.

Comment: Okay, so I just printed out the headers because after I added the line of code you told me to, instead of echoing a blank screen, it is now echoing out the login.php page. I checked the headers and I have updated the code above to reflect what it is saying.

Comment: 1. make sure you are CURLing the form action attribute from the login form. 2. double check your login credentials.

Comment: FYI: you can have sessions with out cookies

Comment: @Dagon As far as i know they wouldn't be any different from any other variable. HTTP is stateless. Explain please - i'm interested.

Comment: @MarshallHouse I have double checked the login credentials and the action URL and they are both correct. I checked the cookies.txt file and it shows that I logged in.

Comment: @Dagon can you please explain in more detail? Thanks

Comment: session ids can be populated in the url or a cookie, url use to be standard when cookie support was poor, now its the other way around.

Comment: oh... yeah. I don't count that as a practical alternative. That would ruin caching.

Comment: Any idea why my code is not working? I am just getting a 302 redirect message.

Comment: @three3 there is something obvious wrong with your actual code here. I couldn't begin to tell you what since i know nothing about the site you are logging into or submitting from.

Comment: Here is my cookies.txt file information: www.example.com FALSE / FALSE 0 PHPSESSID 84f75dbb820a024fbe25a1c7ebd9fa78
www.example.com FALSE /User/ FALSE 1684972937 current_page Home.php

Comment: What do all of the FALSE mean?

Comment: just standard cookie parameters. you need to debug the target site more and figure out if your login credentials get manipulated onsubmit or if there are other fields to submit.. etc. use your browser developer tools.

Answer (score 0):

there are many types of values in PHP that produces no output when `echo`'ed. off the top of my head, this includes `bool(false)` , `NULL`, and `""` (emptystring). and probably more. in order to see the difference between them, use `var_dump` , which differentiate between all of them. $result2 may be either emptystring or bool(false), and its impossible to tell which, using echo. however, given that the http headers contain `Content-Length: 0` , its almost certainly emptystring. also,  $username and $password is not urlencoded, so if they contain any chararacters with special meaning in `application/x-www-urlencoded`-format, the server will recieve the wrong username/password. this include spaces, `&`, `=`,`?` , and several others. they need to be url-encoded, like `$postdata='email='.urlencode($username).'&password='.urlencode($password);`, another thing is, when debugging curl code, enable CURLOPT_VERBOSE, it prints a lot of useful debugging information.

but @Marshall House is correct, the server sends a `HTTP/1.1 302 Moved Temporarily` url redirect, which it expect you to follow... and you don't. and you can tell curl to automatically follow http redirects, using CURLOPT_FOLLOWLOCATION.